# Is usage of "deserve" without reference to subject’s individual conduct or character a separate sense?

Tags: word-usage, political-correctness

Dictionaries continue to define the verb *deserve* in terms of qualities or actions by which a person individually merits or earns good or ill:

> Do something or have or show qualities worthy of (a reaction which rewards or punishes as appropriate) ([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deserve))
>
> To be worthy of; merit ([American Heritage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deserves) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deserve))
>
> to merit, qualify for, or have a claim to (reward, punishment, aid, etc.) *because of actions, qualities, or circumstances* ([Random House Kernerman Webster](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deserves), emph. added)
>
> To have acquired, and thus to have, a rightful claim to; to be entitled to, in return *for services or meritorious actions*, or sometimes *for ill deeds and qualities* (OED, rev. 1895, “Now the ordinary sense,” emph. added)

More and more, though, I seem to encounter this verb in contexts where a person’s claim to some benefit appears to derive from nothing but the person’s mere existence. Such usage is of course routine in advertising—“You deserve a break today!”—where it serves as an example of Socrates’ point [that the art or rather knack of persuasive rhetoric is a species of flattery](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Plat.%20Gorg.%20463&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0178). But even where the subject, the alleged deserver, is not the addressee, the verb seems to have been decoupled from any knowledge or assessment of that person’s individual conduct or character. Thus “[everyone deserves healthcare](https://www.theodysseyonline.com/everyone-deserves-healthcare)” seems to have become the prevailing or at least a common way to express the notion that healthcare is a human *right.*

One might consider this increasingly common usage of *deserve,* without any implication concerning the deserver’s individual conduct or character, to be a distinctly liberal usage, politically, in that liberals as a group are sometimes supposed to differ from conservatives in *(a)* believing humanity on the whole to be good and *(b)* shying away from being “judgmental” in individual cases, including hypothetical ones.

My question is, Does this “liberal” or possibly even P.C. sense of *deserve* constitute a distinct sense that dictionaries just have not caught up with yet?

Comment: Are you asking if the word _deserved_ takes on a different meaning when misapplied or frivolously granted?

Comment: @YosefBaskin More or less, yes, but that terminology smacks of “peeving” regarding this usage, and that tends to be frowned upon hereabouts.

Comment: One thing you could do is remove three of your definitions, as they repeat the same idea: deserve = merit. That is, if you want to sound less insistent.

Comment: Those definitions are by no means all synonymous: the whole question may well turn on whether the “qualities” or “circumstances” mentioned in some but not all of them might properly include just being alive and human.

Comment: @Brian Donovan: Regardless of terminology, I think the entire thrust of the question is at least *bordering* on a peeve. Etymologically, as OED points out, ***deserve*** derives from *Latin **dēservīre** to serve zealously, well, or meritoriously ...  hence, in late popular Latin, **to merit by service***. But the difference between being "entitled" ***by [birth]right*** as opposed to ***as a consequence of behaviour / past deeds*** is often deliberately blurred for various reasons.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is predicated on an error. If healthcare is indeed a human right, then RHKW's 'qualify for, or have a claim to (... aid, etc.) because of ... circumstances' certainly licenses 'everyone deserves healthcare'. ' ... dictionaries just have not caught up with [this sense] yet' is erroneous.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, yeah, let's consider this "distinctly liberal" usage from that lefty manifesto [*The Christ Centered Marriage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=S7UJJCed5G4C&q=inauthor:%22Neil%20T%20Anderson%22%20%22deserves%20respect%22&dq=inauthor:%22Neil%20T%20Anderson%22%20%22deserves%20respect%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_26CP2OXSAhVDRCYKHTE5AcYQ6AEIGjAA) by that left-winger Neil T Anderson, the founder of Freedom in Christ Ministries:

> Everyone **deserves respect**, but only those who earn it gain trust.

This radically left-wing usage is of long standing, as we can see from [*The Albany Law Journal*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EaQtAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA284&dq=%22deserves%20respect%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAuZjR1eXSAhWB2SYKHYkoB0I4ChDoAQhFMAg#v=onepage&q=%22deserves%20respect%22&f=false) in 1878, no doubt one of the leading proponents of political correctness of is era:

> A decision of a court is law, and **deserves respect** and obedience, .... The law as pronounced should, *upon its face*, invite respect and obedience,.... (*emphasis* mine)

The *OED* records both senses (since 1292)-- 1) to have a rightful claim to something and 2) to be entitled to something by virtue of one's actions of qualities, meritorious or ill.

Comment: Long time no hear, hope you're OK.